# C#, Concatenate integer and string into var

Tags: c#, concatenation, microsoft-chart-controls

How to concatenate integer and string into var?

```
int a; int x=2; int y=7200;
a=x*y;
var B=a+"D"; // How to concatenate this to turn it 14400D
// I need use this in the code that changes the AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval.
// We can not use string concatenation here.
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval=B;
```

Comment: You code looks fine to me. If you try to write your `B`, it will print `14400D`. What do you want exactly?

Comment: var B = a.ToString() + "D"; Would that do the trick?

Comment: Forgive me. Unwittingly solved my problem.
It was just what I needed. I tested with this code and it worked.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Interval` takes a double, could you not just convert the int to a double instead?

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = Convert.toDouble(a);
```

- [Interval method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle.interval.aspx)
- [toDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

By Looking your code. I think you need this code it seems.?

```
int a; int x = 2; int y = 7200;
a = x * y;
var B = a.ToString() + "D"; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = B;

OR

int a; int x = 2; int y = 7200;
a = x * y;
String aValue = a.ToString() + "D";
var B = aValue;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = B;
```

Exactly If your requirement this, then I would suggest first one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `int a;` write `double a;` and:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = a;
```